# Replace UUID value in fstab using sed

Tags: linux, replace, sed

My fstab is somewhat like the following:

```
UUID=somevalue1  
UUID=somevalue2
```

I want to edit the 2nd UUID. How do I do that using sed?

So after editing the fstab would look like follows:

```
UUID=somevalue1
UUID=somevalue3
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: There is the sed s command, you could use that, see `man sed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know `somevalue2`, then you can just do something like

```
VALUETOREPLACE='somevalue2'
sed "s/^UUID=$VALUETOREPLACE$/UUID=somevalue3/" </etc/fstab
```

If you don't know, you can just do the replacement 2nd time `UUID=` is found in the fstab:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/UUID=[A-Fa-f0-9-]*/UUID=somevalue3/2' </etc/fstab
```

You can try changing that `2` to `3` or anything else select another n-th match. Also note that on modern systems /etc/fstab frequently has this line in it:

# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices

which also happens to have `UUID=` in it and that may mess your numbering.